# Android canvas - some rectangles not drawn when touching top border after translation

Tags: android, canvas, bounds

I am drawing a number of rectangles on a canvas. I translate the canvas on mouse click and drag event, using canvas.translate(x,y). Certain rectangles go blank (not drawn) when they just touch the top border after dragging. Anyone know what the problem might be?

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises when you create the rectangle as:
canvas.drawRect(leftx, bottomy, rightx, topy), instead of canvas.drawRect(leftx, topy, rightx, bottomy)